# unix.se reputation visible in careers.so CV?

Tags: discussion

Once the unix SE goes out of beta, will the rep be visible in the careers CV view? I think it makes sense for people looking for UNIX-related jobs.

Comment: This might have to be asked on meta.SO infact it may already have been.... idk... although I upvoted it's probably not right for here.